# How to detect a connection without logging in on the console (TTY0)

Tags: linux, serial-port, detection

I was wondering what possibilities are available to detect a connection on a tty. My goal is to create an alert in case someone tries to watch what I am doing through the console

First I though about `who`, which allows to see wether someone is connected and on what tty, but let's say this user isn't logged in, is there still a way of detecting that a tty is opened? Maybe with /dev/tty? Or is it possible to know how many file descriptors are pointing to the file /dev/console and what processes are using the hardware/io? Or maybe using hardware detection with vcs? I actually have no idea how to use/test those.

Answer (score 0):

> let's say this user isn't logged in

Each process belongs to some user. The only way to run some code and not being logged in is to write this code in kernel.

> I was wondering what possibilities are available to detect a connection on a tty

Try this:

```
$ lsof /dev/tty0
```

`lsof` is a tool for observe open files.

For example, serial console for my development board is `/dev/ttyUSB0`. So I opened `minicom` session and also made `cat` for my TTY file:

```
$ minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0
$ cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and checked this:

```
$ lsof /dev/ttyUSB0
```

which gave me:

```
COMMAND   PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF   NODE NAME
minicom 13299  joe    3u   CHR  188,0      0t0 135832 /dev/ttyUSB0
cat     13310  joe    3r   CHR  188,0      0t0 135832 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

From this output you can figure out, who (`USER`) connected to your TTY, and whic program he used (`COMMAND`, `PID`).

After closing `minicom` session and `cat`, `lsof` doesn't print anything.

Also it can be done using `w` command:

```
$ w | grep ttyUSB0
```

Output:

```
joe      pts/2    :0     17:57    2:47   0.12s  0.00s minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0
joe      pts/3    :0     17:58    2:39   0.08s  0.00s cat /dev/ttyUSB0
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to be watched in the way described above (i.e. via open descriptor), you can do next.

Let's say you are using `/dev/ttyUSB0`. To connect to your console via this file, you must open it first (no matter which way, e.g. using `cat` or `minicom` etc.). Once you have opened it, your session can be seen by other users (e.g. by root) just looking if there are open file descriptors for that file (`lsof /dev/ttyUSB0`).

Now, TTY devices are just character devices, and you can create your own files (nodes) for those devices. Let's see closely to `/dev/ttyUSB0` file:

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Output:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Mar  4 16:07 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Here `c` indicates that this is character device, and we can see that it has major number `188` and minor number `0`. Let's create our own node (file) for this device.

```
$ cd /tmp
$ sudo mknod some_tricky_name c 188 0
$ sudo chown root:dialout some_tricky_name
$ sudo chmod 644 some_trickyname
```

Now you can connect to this file instead of `/dev/ttyUSB0` and nobody's gonna see you:

```
$ minicom -D /tmp/some_tricky_name
```

Still, if you are gonna run some shell in this TTY, good administrator still can catch you, looking to `/var/log/auth.log`. But I believe this technique prevents you from being caught using `w` or `lsof` commands.

Comment: What i meant by not logged in is, when you start ubuntu server, at the logging screen you can press alt+left to see the logs of the console, this corresponds to tty0 and i would like to detect someone watching this. Let me try with your solution.

Comment: I am afraid your solution doesn't work, W only show logged in people, and lsof doesn't print anything (i tried it on /dev/console, tty0, vcs..) –

Comment: Ah, I completely misinterpreted your question. So, you are the guy who works with TTY (wow, it rhymes :) ), and you don't want some other guy to see this. And my answer says how to see that you are working with TTY, but doesn't say anything about how to tell if **you** are being watched :)

Comment: Exactly! Yes I am that kind of guy :), I wonder if it is possible though, but I am not sure I completly understand ttys, what are the differences bewteen the one from /dev and the one is /sys/class, and why are there ttys, ttySs, and vcs/vcsa ones too. Where is the central node that is the common point of all these?

Comment: I have added **UPDATE** to my answer, please see if it helps. As for TTYs: in `/dev` you have device files (nodes) for your TTY devices. You can figure out your device by reading `/proc/devices` file, looking into `Character devices:` section. From there you can figure out major number for your device. Knowing that, you can easily create your own node (like in `/dev`) using `mknod` command. Also you can get this information reading `dev` and `uevent` files in `/sys/class/tty/ttyUSB0` directory (those files are just kernel interface for providing information about device).